# How to interpret results returned by model.predict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to make a neural network that can identify if there is a cat in a picture. I found [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) on tensorflow website and tried to adapt it to my problem. The tutorial is for classifying cats and dogs, but since I only want to detect cats, I changed the categories to cats and non-cats.

For non-cats I downloaded a dataset of random images.

I added two generators to the code from the tutorial:

```
test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                               directory=test_dir,
                                                               target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                               class_mode='binary')

pred_data_gen = pred_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                 directory=pred_dir,
                                                                 target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                                 class_mode='binary')
```

And then tested the model like this:

```
print('\n# Evaluate on test data')
results = model.evaluate_generator(test_data_gen)
print('test loss, test acc:', results)

print('\n# Generate predictions')
predictions = model.predict(pred_data_gen)
print(len(predictions))
print(predictions)
```

That's the output:

```
# Evaluate on test data
test loss, test acc: [0.45212748232815003, 0.9324082]
# Generate predictions for custom samples
256
[[ -8.023465  ]
 [ -7.781438  ]
 [ 50.281197  ]
 [-10.172492  ]
 [ -5.1096087 ]
 [ 43.0299    ]
 [ 21.416649  ]
 ...
 [-10.866359  ]
 [-14.797473  ]
 [ 84.72212   ]
 [ 23.712345  ]
 [ -6.4916744 ]
 [-18.384903  ]
 [ 33.10642   ]]
```

The test accuracy is very high, but I have no idea what these results mean. I thought they should be between 0 and 1, but these even have negative values. How should I interpret these results?

EDIT:

This is my model (before adding the sigmoid activation function to the last layer):

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])
```

I changed the last layer to `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` and the output looks like this:

```
# Evaluate on test data
test loss, test acc: [0.714477022488912, 0.5949367]

# Generate predictions for custom samples
256
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 ...
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
```

All predicted values are ones, even though only half of the images are cats in the test set.

EDIT2:

Here is how I compile and fit the model:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=total_train // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_data_gen,
    validation_steps=total_val // batch_size
)
```

Comment: try to apply Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') in your last layer

Comment: Please share the code of your model

Comment: @CodePope Edited post.

Comment: Can you paste full code, especially the bits where you compile and fit?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Added more code.

Comment: The rest of the code is the same as in the tutorial I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last layer in your model is a `Dense` layer with a single neuron. Since no parameters have been passed to it, by default it has linear activation. User @Code Pope indicated that it is a "failure" (mistake in Tensorflow docs?). It isn't, the code is perfectly fine.

Your loss function computes binary crossentropy and it can easily work with linear activation. In fact computing sigmoid is just a little extra that is not needed. The ANN will output negative values for one class and positive for the other one. They are not normalised, but are so-called `logits` - that's why you are saying in your loss function `from_logits=True`.

How to get predictions:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

images, actual = next(train_data_gen)
predictions = model.predict(images)
predictions = (predictions > 0).flatten()
accuracy_score(results, pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sigmoid function for scale outputs to [0, 1]

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/sigmoid

Comment: Thanks! I changed the last layer `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`, and now all the predicted values are `1.`. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If you change last layer Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') for prediction It's fine but you must beware when you train a new one again because this line tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), it's mean you compute the loss from Dense(activation=None) you must change it to False. However, I don't recommend this for advanced ML projects because you will lose some number significant when you apply sigmoid before compute loss.

Answer (score 1):

In the sample you have linked ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification), there is failure. In the last `Dense` layer, there must be a sigmoid function to have a value between 0 and 1. The original sample is from the book `Deep Learning for Python` from Francois Chollet and the sample is from chapter 5.2. The sample is available on github and I recommend you to use it: [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.2-using-convnets-with-small-datasets.ipynb).
I have used the sample and it works fine. Your edited model looks fine, but I am not sure if you have created the right folder structure for your images and therefore for your `ImageDataGenerator`. I have trained the model and then loaded an image to predict:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
img_path = '/Users/CodePope/Downloads/catsdogs/cats_and_dogs_smalla/test/dogs/dog.1500.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150,150))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x /=255.
model.predict(x)
```

The result is the following:

```
array([[0.8290838]], dtype=float32)
```

which looks fine, as 0 is for cat and 1 is for dog.
For a cat image we have:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
img_path = '/Users/CodePope/Downloads/catsdogs/cats_and_dogs_smalla/test/cats/cat.1500.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150,150))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x /=255.
model.predict(x)
```

Result:

```
array([[0.15701984]], dtype=float32)
```

And this is in spite of the fact that I have just trained the model for five epochs with a validation accuracy of 0.67.

Comment: I checked and the images are loaded correctly. What about what @Thananchai wrote? Should I change `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` to `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)`?

Comment: @WojtekWencel If you use the sigmoid activation function then it is not necessary to set `from_logits` to `True`.

Comment: This isn't true, there does not have to be "sigmoid" in the last layer. Linear activation works just fine, you just need to know how to interpret the last layer (which is then simply a score).

Comment: @Tracewski, it does not make sense to normalize your images and then have a linear output funtion which outputs in the interval (-infinity,infinity).